# AntD Tables and Input fields per Card

Tags: reactjs, datatables, antd

I have a cards with tables inside but once an edit button is clicked, some of the columns of the tables will be input fields.

But I'm having a problem with my code. I'm getting same value from input change of the field.

Here's my code

EditableTable.js

```
function EditableTable({
  columns,
  dataSource,
  pagination = false,
  hasEdit = false,
  renderColumn,
 }) {
   const footer = () => (
    <table>
     <thead className="ant-table-thead">
      <tr>
        <td colSpan="1" className="ant-table-cell">
          <span>Total</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
);

const tableColumns = () => {
  if (hasEdit) {
    return columns.map(column => {
    if (column.hasFields) {
      return {
        title: column.title,
        dataIndex: column.dataIndex,
        key: column.key,
        render: (text, record, index) =>
          renderColumn(text, record, index, column.key),
        };
      }

      return column;
    });
  }
  return columns;
};

return (
  <div>
    <Table
      columns={tableColumns()}
      dataSource={dataSource}
      pagination={pagination}
      footer={footer}
    />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's where I call my component

```
const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState({
  targets: ['', ''],
  achievements: ['', ''],
  ratings: ['', ''],
});

const dataSource = [
{
  key: 0,
  title: 'I. Operational Excellence',
  hasEdit: true,
  listing: [
    {
      key: '0',
      competency: 'Edward King 0',
      target: '',
      achievement: '',
      weight: '',
      rating: '',
      remarks: '',
      score: '',
    },
    {
      key: '1',
      competency: 'Edward King 1',
      target: '',
      achievement: '',
      weight: '',
      rating: '',
      remarks: '',
      score: '',
    },
  ],
},
{
  key: 1,
  title: 'II. Financial Contribution',
  hasEdit: true,
  listing: [
    {
      key: '0',
      competency: 'Edward King 0',
      target: '',
      achievement: '',
      weight: '',
      rating: '',
      remarks: '',
      score: '',
    },
    {
      key: '1',
      competency: 'Edward King 1',
      target: '',
      achievement: '',
      weight: '',
      rating: '',
      remarks: '',
      score: '',
    },
  ],
 },
];

const handleChange = (e, key, index) => {
  const fields = formFields;
  fields[`${key}s`][index] = e.target.value;
  setFormFields({ ...fields });
};

const renderColumn = (text, record, index, key) => {
  if (isEdit) {
    return (
      <Form.Item>
        {getFieldDecorator(`${key}-${index}`, {
          rules: [
            {
             required: true,
            }, 
          ],
        })(
          <Input
            placeholder="Input text"
            onChange={e => handleChange(e, key, index)}
          />,
        )}
      </Form.Item>
    );
  }

  return formFields.targets && formFields.targets[index];
};

{ dataSource.map(item => (
   <Card key={item.key} className="datatable" title={item.title}>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSave}>
        <EditableTable
         hasEdit={item.hasEdit}
         dataSource={item.listing}
         columns={columns}
         renderColumn={(text, record, index, key) =>
           renderColumn(text, record, index, key)
         }
        />
      </Form>
    </Card>
 ))}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to adapt your `dataSource` if you want to persist the changes.

Just have a look at the [example](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-edit-cell) in [Antd Table docs](https://ant.design/components/table/#How-To-Use). The depending [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4h53s?file=/index.js:2588-2598) has a full featured running version.

Code from the CodeSandbox to handle an input change:

```
  handleSave = row => {
    const newData = [...this.state.dataSource];
    const index = newData.findIndex(item => row.key === item.key);
    const item = newData[index];
    newData.splice(index, 1, { ...item, ...row });
    this.setState({
      dataSource: newData,
    });
  };
```